# How to propagate attributes to child or inherit from parent?

Tags: rust, open-telemetry

Many of my spans are more useful if they inherit many attributes from the parent. Performing queries using Honeycomb for example, it's not possible to query spans based on properties that parent or child spans might have, and many of the attributes of the parents are relevant to the specific span for querying it in isolation. Other than recording them manually (if they're in scope when the child span is created), or perhaps pushing attributes that are intended to be inherited into baggage, and pulling them out on a per-span basis, what are my options here?

How do I propagate attributes to child spans?

Comment: Don't know about `Honeycomb` but in `jaeger` one can easily search spans by specific tag and later open whole trace for detailed investigation. "many of the attributes of the parents are relevant to the specific span for querying it in isolation" - could please elaborate on this? What are use-cases?